# dup2 bad file descriptor

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I am trying to implement pipe to my shell. Right now it can handle normal commands like ls, who, date etc..

By reading a lot and going in to other stack overflow posts to check how pipe is supposed to work i have come up with this code that i will demonstrate for you guys. The function basically takes in a command that is should process.

```
void
runCommand(Command *cmd){

    char **pl = cmd->pgm->pgmlist;
    int status;
    Pgm *p = cmd->pgm;

    //Count the number of pipes and create the right number of filedescriptors
    int numPipes = countPipes(cmd->pgm);
    int pipefds[2*numPipes];

    //Pipe the file descriptors here and check if there was an error.
    for(int i = 0; i < (numPipes); i++){
        if(pipe(pipefds + i*2) < 0) {
            perror("couldn't pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    pid_t pid, wpid;


    int fdr;
    int fd;

    int j = 0;
    while(p != NULL) {

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            // Child process
            if (cmd->bakground == 1) // Check if it should be running in the background, if so, assign a new PID
            {
                setpgid(pid, 0);
            }

            // Check if RSTDOUT is on or not
            if(cmd->rstdout != NULL){

                fd = open(cmd->rstdout, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC , S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
                //fclose(fopen(cmd->rstdout, "w"));
                printf("in first\n");
                dup2(fd,1);
                close(fd);
            }

            // Check if RSTIN is on or not
            if(cmd->rstdin != NULL) {

                fdr = open(cmd->rstdin, O_RDONLY);
                printf("in second\n");
                dup2(fdr, 0);
                close(fdr);
            }

            //if not last command
            if(p->next){
                printf("in third\n");
                if(dup2(pipefds[j + 1], 1) < 0){
                    perror("dup2");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            //if not first command&& j!= 2*numPipes
            if(j != 0 ){

                printf("in fourth: %d\n", j);
                if(dup2(pipefds[j-2], 0) < 0){
                    perror(" dup2");///j-2 0 j+1 1
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                }

            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 2*numPipes; i++){
                    printf("in fifth\n");
                    close(pipefds[i]);
            }

            j += 2;
            printf("%s\n",pl[0] );
            if (execvp(pl[0], pl) == -1) {
                perror("lsh");
            }

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        else if (pid < 0) {
            // Error forking
            perror("lsh");
        } 
        else if(cmd->bakground != 1){ // check in the parent process if it was running in background, if so dont call for wait()
            // Parent process
            j+=2;

            pl = p->pgmlist;    
            p = p->next;
            for(int i = 0; i < 2 * numPipes; i++){
                printf("in sixth\n");
                close(pipefds[i]);
            }

            int returnStatus;    
            waitpid(pid, &returnStatus, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.

            if (returnStatus == 0)  // Verify child process terminated without error.  
            {
               printf("The child process terminated normally.");    
            }

            if (returnStatus == 1)      
            {
               printf("The child process terminated with an error!.");    
            }

        } 
        else
            printf("Child process with ID %d is running in background\n",pid );
    }

}
```

Normal commands still work fine however when i try to do this i get the following result.

```
> ls | wc
>  dup2: Bad file descriptor
```

As i read about it i think it means that i simply close to early or i am handling my file descriptors badly. I have tried to fix it but with no success i turn to you guys which might see something that i cant see. If you need any further information please just comment and i i will do my best to assist.

******EDIT 1******

I added printf to every dup2 or close that i used, naming them first, second , third etc just to know exactly in which dup or close that i get the error in . This was the result when i ran the command:

```
> ls | wc
in sixth
in sixth
in third
in sixth
in sixth
in fourth: 2
 dup2: Bad file descriptor
```

So know we know where it fails at least.

******EDIT2******

i also added what filedescriptors we are writing or reading from or closing:

```
In parent closing fd: 0
In parent closing fd: 1
in child third writing to fd: 1
In parent closing fd: 0
In parent closing fd: 1
in child fourth reading from fd: 0
 dup2: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Werror -g -o myprog && gdb --args myprog`

Comment: You forgot to add gcc myprog, anyway would you like me to add the errors given from the output? @JonathonReinhart

Comment: I forgot the `myprog.c`, sorry. But no, I want you to fix all of the errors from compilation. I suspect your program might work when you do. This is why we have compiled languages - to detect programming problems before runtime.

Comment: Every error that i had  was " implicit declaration of fork et.c. And the way i see i do not implement fork or all the other functions wrong? @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Assuming Linux, you can run under `strace -f -o /path/to/output/file ...` to see what's going on at the system call level.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem with dup2 is here:

```
if(cmd->rstdin != NULL) {

                fdr = open(cmd->rstdin, O_RDONLY);
                dup2(fd, 0);
                close(fdr);
            }
```

you are opening "fdr" but then you use "fd" in dup2. "fd" is not open or already been closed inside a previous if {}. Moreover in both these conditionals you do not check the return value of dup2.

Comment: Just changed it to fdr in dup2 but still does not work. Also that that part has nothing to do with pipe. That part has to do if i am using these commands ls < or > text.txt